# convert general array into circular arry

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

I faced a problem that needs to convert a general Array into a CircularArray. The solution uses below function to rotate and retrieve the virtual index in CircularArray:

```
head = 0;
int[] items;


int convert(int index){
  if(index < 0){
      index += items.length;
  }
  return (head+index)%items.length;
}
```

Other methods that use above function

Rotate:

```
void rotate(int shiftRight){
    head = convert(shiftRight);
}
```

set:

```
set(int i, int xxx){
    items[convert(i) = xxx;
}
```

Can anybody help me explain how this function works? Why we need to %items.length?

Thanks

Comment: The modulo operator is simply there to avoid overflows; for any `x`, `x % n` is guaranteed to return a result between 0 and n - 1, which is precisely what is needed for an array with n elements.

Comment: Your set method won't compile.

Comment: shouldn't the mod line happen before the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is a example of a circular array(Queue) I did some time ago. Whenever adding an element use Inc() function to calculate the position.

Hope this helps your problem.

```
public class MyQueue {
public int front,rear,size;
int Q[];
MyQueue(int x){
    Q=new int[x];
    front=0;
    rear=-1;
    size=0;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return size==0;
}
public boolean isFull(){
    return size==Q.length;
}
public int Inc(int x){
    if(front==Q.length-1){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return ++x;
    }
}
public void push(int x) throws Exception{
    if(!isFull()){
        Q[Inc(rear)]=x;
        size++;
    }else{
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
public int pop() throws Exception{
    if(!isEmpty()){
        size--;
        int temp=Q[front];
        Inc(front);
        return temp;
    }else{
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
public int top() throws Exception{
    if(!isEmpty()){         
        int temp=Q[front];          
        return temp;
    }else{
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
}
```

Inc function get's the current position as a parameter and if it is the end of the array and filled size is not equal to array length(that means there are free space in the front) returns the front position and if position is in the middle of the array it will increment normally.